# Has anyone ever heard of a launchd file named LIsteners, with a capital “I”?

Tags: macos

2018 MacBook Pro 2.6 i7, 32gb

Mac OS X Mojave 10.14.5

Has anyone ever heard of a launchd file named LIsteners, with a capital “I”?

I was running Safari 12.1.1 with 4 tabs opened.
I opened Open Office version 4.1.6 and
In about 120 seconds, the fans in the laptop were screaming and the bottom was extremely hot.
I rebooted before thinking of viewing the console messages.

Was going to look at logs to determine a possible cause when I discovered redirects of tmp, etc and var into private/

Listing private/tmp show me a couple of launchd directories and a directory called powerlog

```
drwxrwxrwt  5 root  wheel  160 Jun 27 06:26 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 root  wheel  192 Apr 16 18:09 ..
drwx------  3 edge  wheel   96 Jun 27 05:53 com.apple.launchd.lcCeZtOOzC
drwx------  3 edge  wheel   96 Jun 27 05:53 com.apple.launchd.vgVBnACnJW
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel   64 Jun 27 05:52 powerlog

ls -la com.apple.launchd.lcCeZtOOzC gives me:

drwx------  3 edge  wheel   96 Jun 27 05:53 .
drwxrwxrwt  5 root  wheel  160 Jun 27 06:26 ..
srw-rw-rw-  1 edge  wheel    0 Jun 27 05:53 Listeners
```

I swear, when I did this the first time, Listeners had a capital I,  like this LIsteners

Although it is not listed here, If I 'more' LIsteners, even now,  I get
**LIsteners is not a regular file (use -f to see it)**
I was afraid to open it before asking around about it.

So my question is: 
Has anyone ever encountered LIsteners and can you tell me if it’s legit or is something listening where it shouldn’t?

Answer (score 0):

This is a socket file used by the Xcode simulator.  Probably the iOS simulator.  Might be used in other circumstances (like for a Catalyst app running in macOS?).

Comment: That makes sense.  I was developing some small iOS apps back then.  Thanks for the input!